# To use existing database on sql server2008 in visual studio 2010 mvc3

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

i have an existing database on local sql server 2008.

what should i do **to access the database** and to **display the contents of that database**.

i am using **visual studio 2010** and i have to make a **mvc3** web application for which i have to access the database.

should **i have to make model classes(entity classes)** or rather can these be generated from my database. please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very open question and any answer will depend a lot on personal preference.  I would suggest that if you are using MVC3 and VS2010 you look at Entity Framaework, Microsofts ORM (Object relational mapper).

[EF MVC Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application%5D%5B1%5D)

You can produce a Model from the Database or Write a Domain model that mirrors the DB using Code First its up to you the tutorial linked explains how.

Alternatives would include Nhibernate, Subsonic and a bunch of other ORMs or just doing it all your self with ado connections and commands.

Comment: do you have a link for the tutorial?